# Mysql ordering by joined table doesn't work

Tags: mysql

This is my sql query. I use it to select some data from three tables using join:

```
SELECT `pages`.`page_id`, `pages`.`content`
FROM (`pages`)
JOIN `comments` ON `pages`.`page_id` = `comments`.`page_id`
JOIN `meta` ON `pages`.`page_id` = `meta`.`page_id`
WHERE DAYOFMONTH ( meta.date ) = 23
AND `pages`.`category` =  '1'
ORDER BY `meta`.`visits` asc
LIMIT 25
```

The problem is that ordering by doesn't work if I filter posts by categories as well, e.i. if this part exists:

```
AND `pages`.`category` =  '1'
```

If I omit this part, it works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To get your query work, move the condition to the join:

```
...
JOIN `meta` ON `pages`.`page_id` = `meta`.`page_id` 
and `pages`.`category` =  '1'
WHERE DAYOFMONTH ( meta.date ) = 23
ORDER BY `meta`.`visits` asc
LIMIT 25
```

Comment: What didn't work?? it doesn't return data or the ordering doesn't work??